# How to perform an async call whose result I need to compute in onKeyEvent of Column Component`s Modifier parameter in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, async-await, android-jetpack-compose

The question is simple. How do I do it or better said, how do I solve calling an async function on user input in Jetpack Compose??

My code:

```
@Composable
fun board = Row() {
  var gameboard: MutableState<Array<IntArray>> = mutableStateOf(/* some value here */)
  Column(Modifier.onKeyEvent(myOnKeyPressedFunction(gameboard)){
    /* some stuff here */
  }
}

private fun myOnKeyPressedFunction(gameboard: MutableState<Array<IntArray>>): (KeyEvent) -> Boolean = {
  when (it.key) {
    Key.directionUp -> {
      val res: Boolean = asyncMethodUpdatingGameboard(gameboard)
      res //so the gameboard should be updated by the time it gets here and 
          //return true and then see the changes
    }
    else -> false
  }
}

private fun asyncMethodUpdatingGameboard(gameboard: MutableState<Array<IntArray>>) {
  val res: Boolean = /* perform some async calls here */
  res
}
```

Problem is I cannot use withContext or async/await because the onKeyEvent does NOT take a suspend function.
If I use CoroutineScope.launch to call the async task, the boolean value gets return before the async task finished and thus the board does not get re-rendered.

Any ideas? Should I try a different architecture? Or a different modifier?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use a delayed function without some `Effect` or `CoroutineScope.launch`, I was able to achieve the Same thing but differently on compose the desktop project with the re-rendering required after updating the `gameboard` mutable State.

##### First, here is the code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Board() {
    val gameboard: MutableState<Array<IntArray>> = mutableStateOf(arrayOf(intArrayOf(1,2)))
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Row {
        Column {
            Text("Value is ${gameboard.value}")
        }
        TextField("", {}, modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
            when (it.key) {
                Key.DirectionUp -> {
                    scope.launch{
                        asyncMethodUpdatingGameboard(gameboard)
                    }
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        })
    }
}

private suspend fun asyncMethodUpdatingGameboard(gameboard: MutableState<Array<IntArray>>) : Boolean {
    delay(1000)
    gameboard.value = arrayOf(intArrayOf(1,2,3))
    return false
}
```

##### Here are the results:

I am using my keyboard Up arrow (I am not cheating )
[image]

##### Here is what I did:

- I created and remembered the coroutine scope in which I will run my asyncTask, which will survive recomposition and be remembered.
- I don't think you can call `onKeyEvent` on a normal Row or Column; I was able to get events on normal TextField
- I added a Text to observe the value of the gameboard.
- Finally, I updated that gameboard in the `asyncMethodUpdatingGameboard` after making it suspending with the `suspend` keyword; as you can see, I used a delay of 1 second.
- The text was updated normally after 1 second.

I hope you can use the sample code to try this ideas in your code.